# Porque me da error el end del proceso?

Tags: plsql

```
    create or replace procedure Asigna3(emp_name in emp.ename%type,
    dept_dname in dept.dname%type)
    IS
    l_emplename emp. empno%type;
    l_depardname dept. deptno%type;

    cursor numempl is
    select empno
    from emp
    where emp.ename like '%'||emp_name||'%';
    begin
    select deptno
    into l_depardname 
    from dept
    where dept. dname
    like dept_dname;
    begin
    open numepl;
    loop
    fetch numpl into empno;
    exit when
    (numpl%NOTFOUND);
    UPDATE emp SET deptno=l_depardname
    WHERE emp.empno=l_depardname;
    END LOOP;
    END Asigna3;// Aquí da error y no se porque
```

Comment: Puedes compartirnos el error que te sale por favor

Comment: A simple vista te sobra un begin